# MySQL nested Select statement with subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am struggeling with a database query for 2 Hours now.
There is the following database structure:
article table

```
+---------------+-------------+
| id            | ordernumber |
+---------------+-------------+
|             1 |        3243 |
|             2 |        3344 |
|             3 |        3423 |
|             4 |        7687 |
+---------------+-------------+
```

variant table

```
+----+-----------+-------+-------+
| id | articleId | stock | price |
+----+-----------+-------+-------+
|  1 |         1 |     3 | 10,99 |
|  2 |         1 |     0 | 10,99 |
|  3 |         1 |     1 | 10,99 |
|  4 |         2 |     0 | 11,99 |
|  5 |         2 |     0 | 11,99 |
|  6 |         2 |     1 | 11,99 |
+----+-----------+-------+-------+
```

I want to get all Articles where all but one variant have 0 stock.
Is this even possible with a plain sql statement? I tried with a subquery, but without success, since the subquery gets executed first and I would need to pass values from the current record of the resultset of the outer query.

Any help is much appreciated.

Edit:
Expected Result:

```
+----+-------------+
| id | ordernumber |
+----+-------------+
|  2 |       3344  |
+----+-------------+
```

Comment: Specify the expected result as well!

Comment: you should always show us what you tried, even if it's not working at all.

Comment: Is the duplicated "5" a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the full information for the variant:

```
select v.*
from variants v
where v.stock > 0 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from variants v2
                  where v2.articleID = v.articleID and
                        v2.stock > 0 and
                        v2.id <> v.id
                 );
```

Note:  this assumes that the duplicated "5" is a typo and that the ids really are unique in the table.

Comment: I think this solved the problem for me. I will check this further and accept it as correct answer when I am done checking. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: It worked flawless. :) Thank you again. But I have a question about this solution. What does the "SELECT 1" in the subquery do?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `group by` and `having`.

```
select articleID
from variants
group by articleID
having count(*) - 1 = count(case when stock = 0 then 1 end)
```